# How to add a Restriction to an inner join?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following NHibernate DetatchedCriteria,

```
return DetachedCriteria.For<MMFund>()
    .CreateCriteria<MMFund>(x => x.DataUniverse)
    .Add<DataUniverse>(x => x.SiteId == 100)
    .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Property<MMFund>(x => x.FundId));
```

which is producing the following SQL:

```
and
    this_.ShareClassReturn_ShareClassId in 
    (
        SELECT f.[Fund_ID] as y0_
        FROM   
            dbo.Fund f inner join CAP.DataUniverse du
              on f.[Fund_TypeID] = du.[DataUniverse_TypeId]
                 and f.[Fund_CountryID] = du.[DataUniverse_CountryID]
        WHERE  fu.[DataUniverse_SiteId] = 100
    )
```

There are many funds in a DataUniverse.

I need to filter this so that I can select only the funds with a country ID of 'ET', so that my query looks as follows:

```
and
    scr.ShareClassReturn_ShareClassId in 
    (
        /* Get funds in universe */
        SELECT f.[Fund_ID] as y0_
        FROM   dbo.Fund f inner join CAP.DataUniverse du
                    on f.[Fund_TypeID] = du.[DataUniverse_TypeId]
                    and f.[Fund_CountryID] = 'ET' // these are the guys I need
        WHERE  du.[DataUniverse_SiteId] = 100 
    )
```

However, I'm not sure what I need to do to the DetachedCriteria in order to make this happen. The problem I'm having is that no matter what I do, it's putting the clause in the wrong place, such as

```
WHERE  du.[DataUniverse_SiteId] = 100  and f.Fund_CountryId = 'ET'
```

when I add the line `.Add(Restrictions.Eq("CountryId", "ET"))` as follows

```
return DetachedCriteria.For<MMFund>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CountryId", "ET"))
    .CreateCriteria<MMFund>(x => x.DataUniverse)
    .Add<DataUniverse>(x => x.SiteId == 100)
    .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Property<MMFund>(x => x.FundId));
```

or it attempts to filter on the wrong table entirely when I specify that the Restriction should be part of the second .CreateCriteria, such as

```
return DetachedCriteria.For<MMFund>()
    .CreateCriteria<MMFund>(x => x.DataUniverse)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CountryId", "ET"))
    .Add<DataUniverse>(x => x.SiteId == 100)
    .SetProjection(LambdaProjection.Property<MMFund>(x => x.FundId));
```

which produces this;

```
WHERE  du.[DataUniverse_SiteId] = 100  and du.[DataUniverse_CountryID] = 'ET'
```

** note - as I'm using the Criteria API, this is actually the Restriction that I'm using:

```
.Add<MMFund>(f => f.CountryId == "ET")
```

I used the `Restriction` terminology because it's more explicit to what I'm trying to achieve. The Criteria API & the other way both produce the exact same results.

Comment: Why do you think `Where` is the wrong place?

Comment: sorry - I should have been more clear I think. It's not whe `Where` that's in the wrong place, it's the `and f.[Fund_CountryID] = 'ET'`

Comment: No, I meant `Where` *is* the proper place for the filter. I'll expand in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think `Where` is the wrong place for the filter? That's where filtering happens.

The generated SQL looks sound. You have two tables joined on their common fields. The `Where` clause is providing the appropriate filtering information. If your *preferred* SQL statement was in place, you'd have data joined on TypeID alone, not the CountryID.

For example, let's say your `Fund` table looks like this

```
TypeID    CountryID
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         2
3         1
4         1
```

And your `DataUniverse` table is the following

```
TypeID    CountryID
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
3         1
3         2
4         1
4         2
```

If you wrote SQL like *you* desire, you would produce a join based on `TypeID` and you would filter `Fund.CountryID = 1`, for example. What would your product look like?

```
F.TypeID    F.CountryID    D.TypeID    D.CountryID
1           1              1           1
1           1              1           2
1           1              1           3
2           1              2           1
2           1              2           2
2           1              2           3
3           1              3           1
3           1              3           2
4           1              4           1 
4           1              4           2
```

Is that your desired output? Yes, you've filtered `Fund.CountryID`, but your join was just on `TypeID`, so you've got all records from `DataUniverse` with that matching type for each `Fund`.

With the join on the two fields and the `Where` filtering the `CountryID`, the result will be the following

```
F.TypeID    F.CountryID    D.TypeID    D.CountryID
1           1              1           1
2           1              2           1
3           1              3           1
4           1              4           1
```

The question is which set of data is the one you expect?